# Codeblocks ctrl + shift + c not working

Tags: code-blocks

I'm using codeblocks for my C++ IDE.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I like to comment out code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

All of a sudden, though, it's stopped working!
How do I turn it back on?

EDIT
commenting out code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does work. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not.
If I go to the menu, click edit, then click copy it out it DOES work. It's just the keyboard shortcut that's broken.

EDIT #2
Whenever I *do* try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I notice this unusual warning message appear:
HTML Help not found at [file directory of project goes here]

Could this be a clue?

Comment: I think that shortcut is <Ctrl>+<Shift>+</> to comment/uncomment lines I think

Comment: I couldn't get that to work unfortunately. Are you sure this is a possibility/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Codeblocks, but I found a way around it.

In general, follow the instructions on [adding a keyboard shortcut](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_Shortcuts_plugin) on the Codeblocks wiki.

- Open *Settings* >> *Editor* .
- On the Editor Tab, scroll down to the Keyboard Shortcuts section.
- Expand the *Edit* section and highlight *Comment*
- On the right, you will see the current assignment of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

The bug is that for some reason Codeblocks does not recognize the keybinding.

The fix is to simply replace it with the same combination.

- Scroll down to the *New Shortcut* box and click inside.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- When Codeblocks says the combo is already assigned to *Comment*, ignore that and click *Add* and *OK*.

After that, the keybinding began to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Edit" menu you will see the Comment/Uncomment options together with the shortcuts, you should check if it's still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If not, then you should install keyboars shortcut plugin, by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

restarting codeblocks, and then in Settings->Editor->Keyboard shortcuts edit it back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have just tried what you said, but it didn't resolve the problem. Could there be a bug? I did check in "Settings->Editor->Keyboard" -- and it was set to Ctrl+Shift+C as expected. (I hadn't changed it, so this wasn't a surprise).

Could there be anything obvious that I'm missing? Perhaps a different keyboard shortcut that I accidentally pressed to turn this feature off?

Comment: I would try to give another shortcut (let's say ctrl+ shift + ~ ) and after that changing it back to Ctrl + Shift + C